# Switch Row Data into column headers

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have as below, an excel worksheet with data arranged in rows with currently with 3 columns having annual data year by year , a column describing the type of data (turnover or sales returns etc) and a product name.

Can anyone please assist me with some advice on how I can load this into an MS Access table with a Product Column, a Year Column and a Data Description Column. Or if you could recommend a better way to manage this data.
More data will be loaded for both previous years and future years.

```
2010       2009       2008     Description   Product Name
---------  ---------  -------  ------------  -------------
1,937,190  1,719,600  816,633  Turnover      Product Name1
  791,788    599,117  743,114  Sales Return  Product Name1
   13,601  1,719,600  816,633  Turnover      Product Name2
  791,788    599,117  743,114  Sales Return  Product Name2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Linked Table in Access that will read the raw Excel data.

[Import or link to data in an Excel workbook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-HA001219419.aspx)

Assuming that your Linked Table is named [ExcelData]

```
2010     2009     2008    Description    Product Name 
-------  -------  ------  -------------  -------------
1937190  1719600  816633  Turnover       Product Name1
 791788   599117  743114  Sales Return   Product Name1
  13601  1719600  816633  Turnover       Product Name2
 791788   599117  743114  Sales Return   Product Name2
```

you could create the following saved query named [qryExcelDataUnpivoted] in Access:

```sql
SELECT [Product Name], 2008 AS Yr, [Description], [2008] AS Amount
FROM ExcelData
UNION ALL
SELECT [Product Name], 2009 AS Yr, Description, [2009] AS Amount
FROM ExcelData
UNION ALL
SELECT [Product Name], 2010 AS Yr, Description, [2010] AS Amount
FROM ExcelData
```

returning

```
Product Name   Yr    Description    Amount 
-------------  ----  -------------  -------
Product Name1  2008  Turnover        816633
Product Name1  2008  Sales Return    743114
Product Name2  2008  Turnover        816633
Product Name2  2008  Sales Return    743114
Product Name1  2009  Turnover       1719600
Product Name1  2009  Sales Return    599117
Product Name2  2009  Turnover       1719600
Product Name2  2009  Sales Return    599117
Product Name1  2010  Turnover       1937190
Product Name1  2010  Sales Return    791788
Product Name2  2010  Turnover         13601
Product Name2  2010  Sales Return    791788
```

Then, you could use that to create a crosstab query if you wanted a separate column for each [Description]

```sql
TRANSFORM SUM(Amount) AS SumOfAmount
SELECT Yr, [Product Name]
FROM qryExcelDataUnpivoted
GROUP BY Yr, [Product Name]
PIVOT Description
```

returning

```
Yr    Product Name   Sales Return  Turnover
----  -------------  ------------  --------
2008  Product Name1        743114    816633
2008  Product Name2        743114    816633
2009  Product Name1        599117   1719600
2009  Product Name2        599117   1719600
2010  Product Name1        791788   1937190
2010  Product Name2        791788     13601
```

Comment: It wouldn't be more efficient to have a column for each Description?

Comment: @Lawrence That's not what I thought you wanted from reading your question. I added it to my answer.

Comment: It worked! Brilliant and fast. Thank you Gord. I have never used CrossTab Queries in Access, but they look like Pivot tables in excel, I will read up on them a bit more. I might have to start calling you Master Yoda for all the help!

Comment: Related but in the long term view, how do you get the data in tables aligned so well? I have tried vertical pipes, spacing, lists but you always the data looking very sharp